Solving $-\frac12\sqrt2x^2\sqrt{\frac yx\sqrt{2-\frac{y^2}{x^2}}+1}-\frac14(x-y)^2+x^2-y^2=0$ and finding two lines
I was solving a geometric problem (link, if intrested), and arrived at this equation:
$$
g(x,y)=-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2} x^{2} \sqrt{\frac{y}{x} \sqrt{2-\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}}} + 1} - \frac{1}{4} {\left(x - y\right)}^{2} + x^{2} - y^{2} = 0
$$
where $x$ is the side of the large square, and $y$ is the side of the small square.
But I'm not for geometry here. To solve the problem I needed to solve for $y$, but I couldn't do that and I struggled to simplify the expression any further, neither math engines such as SageMath and WolframAlpha could. So I decided to graph the implicit function:

On the graph I see that two lines are the solutions:

$y=\frac{x}{5}$ (exact solution, the intended solution to the geometric problem I was solving)
$y \approx -\frac{x}{26}$ (approximate solution, couldn't find exact line equation)

Both lines pass through the origin (0, 0).
Equation $(y-a_1 x)(y-a_2 x)=0$ has exactly two lines as solutions, so I would suggest that the $g(x,y)$ expression could be expressed in the form of product of two line equations. Is that correct?
Assuming $g(x,y)$ can be expressed in form $(y-a_1 x)(y-a_2 x)$, I would expect to obtain the equation for the second line $(y-a_2 x)$ by dividing $g(x,y)$ by the known line equation ($y-\frac{x}{5}$). Both SageMath and WolframAlpha, however, didn't arrive at any simpler expression.
So I have two questions:

Can $g(x,y)$ be indeed expressed in form $(y-a_1 x)(y-a_2 x)$ ? If yes, how can I do that? If not, why? At least intuitively, I'd expect that there can always be found line coefficients $a_1,a_2$ that would match the solutions of an equation that has two line solutions.

At least two real lines are solutions, so the function $y$ is multivalued. I'm not sure about terminology, but I think that one-valued functions that match the solutions of a multivalued function are called branches of that function. Is that possible to find the branches of the function, where one of them I would expect to be $y=\frac{x}{5}$, the other would be the equation for the other real line? How can I solve the equation for all solutions, possibly complex ones as well? How can I find the equation for the other real line?


Thanks!

Divide both sides of the equation by $x^2$: you'll get an equation for $t=y/x$.

BTW: Even Presh's solution to the source problem is a bit overly-complicated, due to expressing things in terms of the circle's radius. Writing $2a$ and $2b$ for the sides of the big and small squares, the right-triangle relation he describes becomes simply $$(a+2b)^2+b^2=2a^2 \quad\to\quad (a - 5 b) (a + b)=0$$ No $\sqrt{2}$s muddying-up the algebra.

$g$ is not a polynomial, and your second line $y\approx-\frac x{26}$ should be $y=-\frac x5$.
Indeed, $g(x,y)=x^2h(y/x)$ (which already proves that the set of solutions is a union of lines containing the origin), where
$$h(t):=-\sqrt\frac{1+t\sqrt{2-t^2}}2-\frac{(1-t)^2}4+1-t^2=-\sqrt\frac{1+t\sqrt{2-t^2}}2+\frac{-5t^2+2t+3}4$$
is defined iff $t^2\le2$, and
$$h(t)=0\iff t=\pm\frac15:$$
these two values can easily be checked to be solutions, and they are the only ones, as can be seen from the graph of $h$.

Here's a somewhat-direct simplification of the equation.
As in other answers, start by dividing-through by $x^2$, and making the substitution $t:=y/x$; with some other tidying-up, the equation becomes
$$
\begin{align}
0 &= 2\sqrt{2+2t \sqrt{2-t^2}} - 3 - 2 t + 5t^2
\tag{1} \\[4pt]
&= 2\sqrt{\left(t+\sqrt{2-t^2}\right)^2} - 3 - 2 t + 5t^2 \tag{2} 
\end{align}$$
Since $|t|\leq1$, we know $t+\sqrt{2-t^2}$ is non-negative, so that we can continue thusly:
$$\begin{align}
0 &= 2\left(t+\sqrt{2-t^2}\right) - 3 - 2 t + 5t^2 \tag{3} \\[4pt]
&= 2\sqrt{2-t^2} - 3 + 5t^2 \tag{4} \\[4pt]
&=  
\left( 7 -5\sqrt{2-t^2}\right)\left( 1 + \sqrt{2-t^2}\right) \tag{5} \\[4pt]
&=  
\left( 7 -5\sqrt{2-t^2}\right)\left( 7 +5\sqrt{2-t^2}\right)\cdot\frac{1 + \sqrt{2-t^2}}{7+5\sqrt{2-t^2}} \tag{6} \\[4pt]
&=  
\left(25t^2-1\right)\cdot\underbrace{\frac{
1 + \sqrt{2-t^2}}{7 +5\sqrt{2-t^2}}}_{\text{strictly positive}} \tag{7}
\end{align}$$
Hence, $t=\pm1/5$, corresponding to the lines $y=\pm x/5$. $\square$

If you expect the solution to be two lines passing through (0,0), then I would substitute $y=cx$ and solve for $c$ (so that the polynomial in $x$ becomes identically zero). That looks like something a computer algebra system should be able to solve.
